# Solving the Helmholtz Equation on a Rectangle with Dirichlet Boundary Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I want to use separation of variables to solve the Helmholtz equation on a rectange in $2D$ with Dirichlet Boundary Conditions:
$$ \Delta u+ u = 0 \quad\text{on D}\quad\quad\quad u(x,y) = f(x,y) \quad\text{on $\partial$D} $$
where D is $[-3,3]^2$. I tried using separation of variables, $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$:
$$ X''Y+XY''+XY=0 \implies \frac{X''}{X}+\frac{Y''}{Y}+1=0 \implies \frac{X''}{X}=-\frac{Y''}{Y}-1=-\lambda^2 $$
So I have two ODEs now:
$$ X''+\lambda^2 X = 0 \quad\text{and}\quad Y''+Y-\lambda^2 Y=0 $$
For the specific problem I want to solve, the BC is given as $f(x,y)=\sin(\frac{\pi x}{6})$. However, I am not sure how to use this to solve for the coefficients that pop up. For example, solving those ODEs as given (assuming for now $\lambda^2>0$) gives:
$$ X(x) = A\cos(\lambda x)+B\sin(\lambda x) $$
Now my thought is to apply the conditions that $X(-3)=-1$ and $X(3)=1$ which gives;
$$ X(3)=1=A\cos(3\lambda)+B\sin(3\lambda) $$
$$ X(-3)=-1=A\cos(3\lambda)-B\sin(3\lambda) $$
Adding these two equations implies that $2A\cos(3\lambda)=0 \implies A=0 \quad \text{or} \quad \lambda = \frac{2\pi n}{3}$.
Subtracting these two equations implies that $B\sin(3\lambda)=1$. But this doesn't exactly seem correct.

Did I make a mistake in my assumption that the separation constant is $-\lambda^2$? Should I have waited to apply the boundary conditions?

My other thought was to maybe do the $Y$ boundary conditions first, however, it's a function of $X$ there so I would have to apply that BC on the product $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$. I was also thinking that I can't just jump to a series solution combining the two without first finding some constraint on the values $\lambda$ can take (i.e. like it being an integer).

Any thoughts, comments, or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to consider the meaning of the BC you have. The Helmholtz eqn is separable in rectangular coordinates, but is your boundary condition separable? Doesn't the function $f=\sin(\pi x/6)$ represent the BC at a boundary controlled by $y$, namely $y=\pm 3$?

Comment: I think if you consider that and re-do the solution step by step, you will find the answer to be something like $u=C\sin\lambda_{x}x\cos \lambda_{y} y$, where $\lambda_{x}=\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\lambda_{y}=\sqrt{1-\lambda_{x}^{2}}$ and $C=1/(\cos3\lambda_{y})$.